# How to pass Json or query string params to ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, get

I am building a filtering area and I have checkboxes, when you click on it does a "get" request to the server to find anything that matches.

I am not sure how to pass these filters values to my get method.

I can't have

```
public IActionResult GetFilterOptions(string param1, param2, etc)
```

Can I pass it in through the `body` like in a post?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="2"  />
<input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="3"  />

$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "PostedHere",
data: { checkedValues: $("#newCheckboxes:checked").serialize() } 
 });
```

Use Post Rather than Get Method

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFilterOptions([FromBody] CheckboxObject model)
{   

    foreach (item in selectedItems)
    {
        //Query Statement goes here
    }


    return Ok(new { result= test });
}

public class CheckboxObject
{
   public List<string> CheckedValues;
}
```

Comment: but, I am not posting any data, I want to grab data.

Comment: if checkbox one has value 1, you can use that condition to query the data needed. let me edit my answer to reflect your request.

Comment: not really, I need the names of whatever the client request is giving me so I can't just name them param1 to param10000. I also don't know if doing a post is the right thing

Comment: @chobo2: I posted an update whereby you can pass an array of values of checkboxes all at ones and iterate through it at the API Layer. you will not need to define an object for each parameters

Comment: what is the datatype on your thing?

Comment: @chobo2: Please, Which datatype are you referring to?

Comment: @chobo2: i made a change.

Answer (score 0):

For a `GET`, you pass parameters in the query string.

**Example:**

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    //note: HttpGet attribute is only one of many ways to template the route
    [HttpGet("/Data/FilterOptions")]
    public IActionResult GetFilterOptions(string paramOne, string paramTwo) { }
}
```

then create a `GET` request with that looks like:

```
localhost:80/Data/FilterOptions?paramOne=abc&paramTwo=xyz
```

Comment: problem is I got like hundreds of combinations of parameters, each item has it's own filters. I would have to do what you did 1000 times to get every combination and maybe only 2 would be filled out or maybe 100. Don't know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `[FromQuery]` and accept an object that contains the filtering logic?

You could look at Telerik’s `DataSourceRequest` as a reference on how the filter is build up and applied.

```
public IActionResult Search([FromQuery] DataSourceRequest request)
```

And the `DataSourceRequest`’s structure would be something like this:

```
{“Filters” : [{“FieldName” : “Username”, “Operator” : “eq”,  “Value” : “John”}, {“FieldName” : ...}, ...]}
```

Comment: Teleriks DataSourceRequest?

Comment: You could build your own. It’s just there for reference. Basically the setup would be similar to the one in this link. What I like though about DataSourceRequest is that it can be used in any model since ‘FieldName’ can be dynamically reflected on the model. https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/january/filtering-and-paging-in-aspnet-core-web-api/